# Modernizr.addTest() is not a function

Tags: javascript, frontend, modernizr

I'm on a Vue-cli project and I got an issue with `Modernizr.addTest()`:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Modernizr.addtest is not a function.
```

I downloaded [Modernizr](https://modernizr.com/download?setclasses) with the `addTest()` option.

Here my case :

```js
const Modernizr = require('../vendors/modernizr-custom');
export class DeviceManager {
    constructor() {
        this.userAgent = '';
        this.init();
    }
    init() {
        this.userAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
        console.log(this.userAgent);
        Modernizr.addTest('webkit',function(){return !!this.userAgent.match(/Android/i);});
    }
}
```

My class is called correctly, I got my `console.log` in the console dev on Chrome.

Can you see something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Uncaught TypeError: Modernizr.addtest is not a function.`

is shown when you are calling the `Modernizr` method that is not present. `Modernizr` itself **is present** (otherwise it would be `ReferenceError: ...not defined`).

It looks like your `Modernizr` build does not include `addTest` as an option. Beware of that; when you are building `Modernizr` from official website this option is off by default.